# Submit button is not working and how to add images and barcodes in pdf file..?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.enemy.myapplication;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

importcom.example.enemy.myapplication.utils.Permission.RxPermissions;
    import com.example.enemy.myapplication.utils.Utility;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Objects;

import crl.android.pdfwriter.PDFWriter;
import crl.android.pdfwriter.PaperSize;
import crl.android.pdfwriter.StandardFonts;
import crl.android.pdfwriter.Transformation;

import static android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;
import static android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
import static crl.android.pdfwriter.PaperSize.LETTER_HEIGHT;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    public Button btnSelect;
    public ImageView ivImage;
    public String userChoosenTask;

    String m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8;
    EditText e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6;
    TextView t1;

    Button save;

    Bitmap thumbnail;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] arraySpinner = new String[]{
                "Male", "Female", "Others"
        };

        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        e1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        e4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        e5 = findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        e6 = findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        Spinner e7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
   arraySpinner);

      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.
     simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        e7.setAdapter(adapter);


        save = findViewById(R.id.Submit);

        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);


     /*   save.setOnClickListener(view -> getRxPermissions()

           .request(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
              Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .subscribe(granted -> {
                    if (granted) {
                        Utility utility = new Utility();
                        utility.selectImage(this);
                    }
                }));*/

        save.setOnClickListener(v -> {


                    m1 = e1.getText().toString();
                    m2 = e2.getText().toString();
                    m3 = e3.getText().toString();
                    m4 = e4.getText().toString();
                    m5 = e5.getText().toString();
                    m6 = e6.getText().toString();
                    m7 = e7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    m8 = t1.getText().toString();




     PDFWriter mPDFWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.LETTER_WIDTH, 
    LETTER_HEIGHT);
mPDFWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, 
   StandardFonts.TIMES_BOLD, StandardFonts.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING);
mPDFWriter.addText(170, LETTER_HEIGHT - 60, 30, "'" + m8 + "'");
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 170, 20, "Name - " + m1);
mPDFWriter.addText(300, LETTER_HEIGHT - 170, 20, "Age - " + m2);
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 200, 20, "Email - " + m3);
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 230, 20, "Phone no. - " + 
 m4);
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 260, 20, "College Name - " 
+ m5);
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 290, 20, "Address - " + 
 m6);
mPDFWriter.addText(40, LETTER_HEIGHT - 320, 20, "Gender - " + m7);


        mPDFWriter.addImage(570, 500, thumbnail, 
       Transformation.DEGREES_270_ROTATION);

       String pdfContent = mPDFWriter.asString();
            outputToFile("Information.pdf", pdfContent, "ISO-8859- 
      1");

                }
        );
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
      String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 
        Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
          PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if (userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from 
           Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void selectImage() {
       final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from 
       Library", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new 
          DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
            {
                boolean result = 
             Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                    if (result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from 
              Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                    if (result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    public void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
        "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new 
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }




    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }


    public RxPermissions getRxPermissions() {
        return new RxPermissions(this);
    }

    public void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, 
     String encoding) {
        File downloads = 
   Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        if (!downloads.exists() && !downloads.mkdirs())
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create download 
   folder");


        File newFile = new File(downloads, fileName);
        Log.e("PDF", "Writing file to " + newFile);

        try {
            newFile.createNewFile();
            try {
                FileOutputStream pdfFile = new 
      FileOutputStream(newFile);
                pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes(encoding));
                pdfFile.close();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved 
         Successfully Location :" + newFile.getCanonicalPath(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("PDF", e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDF", e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        thumbnail = (Bitmap) 
     Objects.requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        if (thumbnail != null) {
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, 
    bytes);

        }
        File destination = new 
       File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {


        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {

   bm=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().
      getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

}
```

i am a beginner and cant able to see the missing component...please help me and tell me the fault..

It will be also good if you can tell me how to add images and barcode on the created pdf files.

Comment: Debug your code when you click the button .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/

Comment: i can't able to find the error

Comment: hey,i solve that problem but when i get pdf file with gallery image,the image is too big

Comment: and can't be clearly printed on that pdf